# Custom Taxonomy Pages by term (and not Taxonomy) with Drupal Views Using Selective Overrides

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have an existing setup of taxonomy terms with the already provided view by Drupal which caters to all taxonomy terms through taxonomy/term/%

Now my view has filters and some of my terms need different filters. For that I need to create custom taxonomy pages by term. I know that through TVI module, I can create custom taxonomy pages but how can I create custom views by term?

When I use TVI, it opens my custom view through all the terms of my selected taxonomy but I want to have a custom view by term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With TVI, you can also override by term, not just vocabulary - just

- go to the edit page for your term,
- if you have the appropriate permission ( "define view for terms in " or "administer taxonomy views integrator" ) the first element in the form will be a fieldgroup labeled "View usage".
- you can tick "Use View Override" to select the appropriate view for this term.